# Unity3d CarController character positioning issue

Tags: unity

I use the unity standard asset components CharacterController and Car and put an empty gameobject onto the car where the camera should be placed when i am inside the car. The empty gameobject is called "Driver". The character controller has an empty called "Head" where its head is.

When i get in the car i perform the following operation

```
GameObject car = GameObject.Find("Car");  
transform.position = car.transform.Find("Driver").transform.position + Vector3.up*1;
transform.parent = car.transform.Find("Driver").transform;
Camera.main.transform.position = car.transform.Find("Driver").transform.position; 
Camera.main.transform.rotation = car.transform.Find("Driver").transform.rotation;
```

and to get out of it, i use the following

```
GameObject car = GameObject.Find("Car");
transform.position = car.transform.position;
transform.parent = null;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity; 
Camera.main.transform.position = transform.Find("Head").transform.position;
```

My problem is when i get into the car and out again, the character is positioned at the position where i have entered the car, so it doesnt seems to update its position with the car movement.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you debug Log car.transnform.position when entering, and also when exiting, and compare the results?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's simpler if you put Driver object as child of Car in the Hierarchy.

Comment: It sounds from the description as though that's where it is already, unless I'm miseading the question.

Comment: Yes, its already child of the car. I ended up disabling the character controller, then move and afterwards enable it again. This way it works.